# How Can I Turn On/Off Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, and Num Lock Programmatically

Tags: java, c++, windows, keyboard

Is there a method to turn on/off Caps Lock, Scroll Lock and Num Lock on Windows?

Please post the code snippet in any language... but my preference is C/C++ or Java.

P.S.  I'm making a Morse Code program which blinks the Scroll Lock LED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java code is...

Get the Toolkit object...

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

To turn on Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, Num Lock...

```
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK, true);
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK, true);
```

To turn off Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, Num Lock...

```
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, false);
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK, false);
toolkit.setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK, false);
```

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming that you are using Windows[1].  This answer will not work on other platforms.Your best bet would be to use the SendInput() API function to simulate WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages on the Scroll Lock Key.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx.

[1]  I base my guess on the following: *nix users (including Mac users) normally state their platform.  Those who are unaware of other platforms are usually Windows users.  :-)

Comment: +1 even just for the footnote :)

Answer (score 0):

On windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can i do this in java???